# ARC properties' new attributes

Tags: objective-c, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I've read the transitioning to ARC notes and I still have a bit of confusion about properties' attributes we shoul/can use... We can use weak in place of assign (with the advantage that the property is set to nil if the object it points to is released), strong in place of retain and what in place of copy? We still use copy alone or do we need to couple strong with copy, such as `property (strong,copy)`.. Maybe I need to practice and read again the doc because ARC is not very clear to me...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Clang ARC documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership.spelling.property) has this to say:

> copy implies __strong ownership, as well as the usual behavior of copy semantics on the setter.

Regarding custom setter methods, it has this to say:

> A property's specified ownership is preserved in its metadata, but
>   otherwise the meaning is purely conventional unless the property is
>   synthesized.

So if you implement custom setters, you're responsible for implementing strong or weak semantics in those setters.

Comment: I don't really understand how you can implement strong and weak semantics,since you do not use retain/release as in retained properties setters

Comment: Your setter would ultimately need to store the object pointer in a variable qualified with either "__strong" or "__weak".  However, it might do other things too, like execute "[self setNeedsDisplay]".

Comment: So you are saying that the ivar that will store the variable  set by the setter should be declared as __strong or __weak?

Comment: Yes. But __strong is the default so you can omit it.

Comment: One last question... if I declare a property as _weak_ and synthesize it, should I take care of declaring the corresponding iVar as `__weak`, since `__strong` is the default if I do not specify anything or is the precompiler (or whatever else is processing that) intelligent to avoid the default and declare the iVar as `__weak`?

Comment: You have to declare the ivar __weak.

Comment: Thank you... maybe it is a _best practice_ to avoid declaring iVars at all, since it is no more necessary because it is automagically inferred from the `@property` declaration...

Answer (score 2):

Copy is implicitly strong, because it creates a copy and transfers ownership.

See this documentation:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW18

Comment: Can we still implement the setter methods for weak and strong properties? With retained properties you implemented setter methods releasing the previous obj and retaining the obj passed to the setter.. What do you do in a strong property setter method, since you don't have to use retain and release anymore... How should weak and strong properties' setters implementation differ with arc, if you chose to implement them? Maybe the difference is the corresponding ivar that must be weak or strong? Excuse me if my questions are trivial....